# Split columns using pandas

Tags: pandas

```
Games                          Home                   Away
Team 1 vs. Team 2              Team 1                 Team 2
Team 1 @ Team 2                Team 2                 Team 1
```

I have a column called Games and want to split it into two new columns label as Home and Away.
For the @ I used `df['Away'] = df['Games'].map(lambda x: x.split('@')[0])` and it works. But I tried using `df['Away'] = df['Games'].map(lambda x: x.split('vs.')[1])` it didn't work.

What am I missing??

Comment: In what sense did it not work? Please post the error, and some data you are using.

Comment: Let's not drive the newcomer out of town with downvotes. This is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the information you provided exactly what is going wrong here. But pandas provides tools that are specific to this kind of work and likely to provide informative errors if things go wrong.

Take a look at the [string methods documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods). Something like `df['Games'].str.extract('(.*)(vs.|@)(.*)')` might be best here. Or the `str.split` method, but I like extract better.